# Upgrading from EE1 to EE2 - How do I manage the add-ons part of the process?

Tags: ee1, upgrade, ee2-upgrades, addons

I'm trying to updgrade from EE1.7.1 to EE2.9.2 by following the steps outlined in the documentation here https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/upgrade_from_1.x.html

The process seems straightforward enough, and I have run through it as a test and it seemed to work (except for addons). To my mind the biggest problem that I have is that I have no idea how to tackle this note right at the top of the upgrade page.

`IMPORTANT
Third-party add-ons from version 1.x will not work with ExpressionEngine 2. Please contact each add-on’s author for a 2.x-compatible version before upgrading, or your site may not function properly. The installer will automatically disable all extensions as part of the upgrade process.`

How do I work out exactly what addons I have and who the author of each addon is? And what happens if there isn't a 2.x compatible version available?

Has anyone put together a more detailed how to guide on the upgrade process somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look the at the folder `system/plugins/`, which is where EECMS 1 keeps its plugins, and look for the name of each plugin or a readme file. The best place to look for new versions is [devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com/). Almost all EECMS add-ons can be found there.

The EECMS 2 plugins are separated into 4 categories:

- fieldtypes;
- accessories;
- modules;
- plugins.

All of the them should be saved on the folder `system/expressionengine/third_party`.

Every add-on have its own update process. Probably for a lot of them, it's just to upload its folder and install it [on CP](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/add-ons/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, Robson. This all seems to be working now. I am able to login into the control panel. Your advice was very helpful. Where I could, I replaced the EE1 version with the EE2 version of the add-in and where I couldn't I left the current version. Next step is sorting out the fieldtype error that I have now.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!