# FieldFrame fieldtype errors after upgrading from EE1 to EE2

Tags: ee2, fieldtype, ee1, upgrade

I've recently upgraded from EE1 to EE2. I had some issues with upgrading the add-ons which you can see [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26423/upgrading-from-ee1-to-ee2-how-do-i-manage-the-add-ons-part-of-the-process), but I now have a working cpanel that I am able to log into, but on the frontend I am getting this error:

```
Error

Unable to load requested field type file:  ft.ftype_id_2.php.

Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory
```

I have done a search for ftype_id_2 in my database and it returned 3 results from the exp_channel_fields table. On the EE1 version of the site these are all FreeForm fields "FF Checkbox Group"

How should I proceed to get these fields across from EE1 to EE2?

Comment: Have you upgraded all the EE add-ons to their EE2 counterparts - especially Freeform? Add-ons (including Fieldtypes) are held in a different location from the EE1 versions.

Comment: **FF** is shorthand for **FieldFrame**, the framework built by Brandon Kelly (Pixel & Tonic) to enable custom fieldtypes in EE1. It's not related to Freeform, which never had a custom channel entry fieldtype  in EE1.

Answer (score 0):

FieldFrame doesn't exist anymore. It was replaced by [Pixel & Tonic Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix).

There's some [update instructions](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/installation.html#upgrading-from-ee1) on their website.